# GTM: Click trigger for button with many nested classes

Tags: html, css, class, google-tag-manager

I have a wordpress instance and my theme renders a button with the following HTML:

```
<a class="ubtn-link ubtn-left tooltip-57583ced327d9"
   href="http://www.google.de" target="_self">
    <span class="cr-animate-gen ubtn ubtn-normal ubtn-no-hover-bg margin-right extension-download ubtn-sep-icon ubtn-sep-icon-at-left ubtn-left"
    data-animate-type="transition.fadeIn" data-hover="" data-border-color="" data-hover-bg="#00ade6"
    data-border-hover="" data-shadow-hover="" data-shadow-click="none" data-shadow="" data-shd-shadow=""
    style="font-size: 16px; border: none; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); opacity: 1; display: inline-block; background: rgb(0, 198, 255);">
        <span class="ubtn-data ubtn-icon">
            <i class="dfd-icon-cloud_download" style="font-size:30px;color:;"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="ubtn-hover"></span><span class="ubtn-data ubtn-text" data-lang="en">Download for free</span>
    </span>
</a>
```

I have a GTM trigger which listens on clicks on all elements and click classes matches a CSS selector. If I debug the click the variables tab tells different Click Classes, dependent on where I click on the button (on the text, on the icon or on the button itself). The different content of the Click Class is the following:

- ubtn-data ubtn-text
- ubtn-hover
- dfd-icon-cloud_download

The problem is, this is too generic. I added the class `extension-download` in the first span. That's the only location I can add extra classes. So I thought of something like the following to define in my trigger as Click Class matches CSS selector: `extension-download > ubtn-data, extension-download > ubtn-hover, extension-download > dfd-icon-cloud_download`, but that doesn't work. How can I easily solve that?

Comment: To refer a classname on CSS you need `.` before the classname.

Comment: I tried that too :-) Doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by seeing if the Element matches a CSS selector which applies to the outermost element and anything inside it:

`Element matches css selector .ubtn-link, .ubtn-link *`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using RegEx to allow multiple Click Classes.

Use "Matches RegEx" and include all the expected Classes in bracket, separated by vertical bar.

Example:

Click Classes Matches RegEx (ubtn-data ubtn-text|ubtn-hover|dfd-icon-cloud_download)

This means any click on Classes with the 3 classes in the bracket will be captured.